# Connector for Microsoft Dynamics: Location of Object Configuration Files

Tags: dynamics-crm, axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-online

I am following the *Connector for Microsoft Dynamics Installation Guide* to setup a connection between Dynamics CRM and AX. I am asked to *Open the object configuration file*.

Where are these object configuration files located?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is one generated .config file per entity in CRM that you have selected for integration.

These object configuration files can be found in:

> %PROGRAMFILES(x86)%\Microsoft Dynamics\Microsoft Dynamics
>   Adapter\Adapters\Microsoft.Dynamics.Integration.Adapters.Crm2011\ObjectConfig\*your organization name*